# SQL UPDATE statement OleDbException

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

when i am running the program it gives the following error

**Syntax error in UPDATE statement.**

the error statement shown in the bold

```
If (foundItem = True) Then
    olDataConnection.Open()
olCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Product Name=" & itemName &   "WHERE Price =" & itemprice & "'", olDataConnection)
olCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parmeterized queries like

```
olCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Product Name= ? WHERE Price =?", olDataConnection)
olCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", itemName);
olCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", itemprice);
```

According to [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) does not support named parameter

> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
olCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Product Name=" & itemName &   "WHERE Price =" & itemprice & "'", olDataConnection)
```

to

```
olCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Product Name='" & itemName & "' WHERE Price =" & itemprice, olDataConnection)
```